# In Objective C how can I get the class name of self at run time?

Tags: objective-c, class, objective-c-runtime

In Objective C 'self' is an instantiation of some class. How can I find out what class it's an instantiation of? IOW I want an NSString containing the name of the class. I know about isKindOfClass but that only tests whether it's a particular class whose name I have to know in advance. If I have 20 classes in my app (or 50) I'd have to write out 20 isKindOfClass statements to find out which class it is, and I'd have to rewrite them to do the same test in a different app. Isn't there a more direct way of getting the class name?

Also, how can I get an NSString containing the name of the method I'm in at run time?

I'd like to use these functions in a run time debugging method.

This question refers to Objective C and iOS.

Comment: `NSStringFromClass(self.class)`, it you're inside an instance method. If you're in a class method, then `self.class` will return the class itself, and not its superclass (i. e. the metaclass); you'll then need to find the metaclass manually, using the runtime functions.

Comment: @RobertL, be aware of things like class clusters. There might be dragons. `isKindOfClass:` should be aware, your code might not.

Comment: "I want an NSString containing the name of the class" Not all classes have names -- metaclasses don't have names, other than perhaps "class X's metaclass"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the class:

`NSStringFromClass([self class]);`

For methods (assuming you are in the method you are interested in):

`NSStringFromSelector(_cmd);`

Side note, `_cmd` is passed just like `self` to every method in Objective C and is a SEL (selector) for the method you are in.

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thank you. I should have known that myself but I forgot about it. What about the name of the current method -- something like __CMD in a macro? I can't give a green check for 9 more minutes.

Comment: yea! I edited my answer to show the method part too.

Comment: @lance could you explain more how _cmd is like self and a SEL in the method you are in both at the same time? Other words, you mean it has the ability to "morph" itself? Thanks.

Comment: In most languages, the variable `self` or `this` is a parameter passed to the method, commonly the first parameter. That's how you have access to it inside the method. The compiler simply passes a pointer or copy of the object you are calling the method on to that method automatically. In Objective C, it ALSO passes a parameter called _cmd that is of the type SEL (commonly known as a selector) to every method.

Comment: You can get more information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html specifically the "Using Hidden Arguments" section.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is this:

```
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

It's long but once you've used  it a few times typing _<kbd>tab</kbd> will autocomplete to `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isMemberOfClass:`  which tells whether the given object is instance of that particular class or not.

You can get the current class name with `NSStringFromClass(self.class)`
You can get the current method name using `NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)`   (_cmd selector which is a hidden argument for each method).